# Regex from javascript to java

Tags: java, javascript, regex

I need java equivalent of these javascript regex:

1. `"abcde".search(/c/); // out: 2`
2. `/[^\d]/.test("123bed567"); // out: true`
3. `"asdgh".match(/\d/); // out: null`

It's really simple one-line solution in javascript (and in php i know too), so i expect a similar one in Java.

Comment: What have you tried and what exactly are you having problems with? Please ask a specific question an not just *convert this for me*.

Comment: I would try using this tool first http://regexpal.com/ Then ask a more specific question relating to a problem you have run into. Cheers

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/ - the Java solutions will probably be more verbose than javascript/PHP.

Comment: this is simple 3 line of code.
if it is so hard write 3 line of code with regexp for a java programmer,  so i don't know how to write it too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("c").matcher("abcde");
System.out.println(matcher.find()?matcher.start():-1);


Matcher matcher2 = Pattern.compile("[^\\d]").matcher("123bed567");
System.out.println(matcher2.find());

Matcher matcher3 = Pattern.compile("\\d").matcher("asdgh");
System.out.println(matcher3.find()?matcher3.group():null);
```

Comment: I can't find one-line solution, but two-line is accessible.

Comment: You can wrap all of these in one line each.

Answer (score 2):

1. `"abcde".indexOf('c');`
2. `"123bed567".matches("^\\d"); //matches, not match. my bad.`
3. `"asdgh".indexOf("\\d");`

Should do it. There are other ways to do it, of course. Maybe you should heed the advice of the first commenter and TELL US WHAT YOU WANT!

Comment: in your 3rd example output is -1 instead of null and second one is not compile

Comment: for the third example, read the javadoc. I think it states that String.indexOf(String regex) will return -1 if the regex does not match. If you can't handle a -1 instead of null... nevermind.

Comment: I think you want just two backslashes, not four, for expressions 2 and 3.

Comment: Absolutely correct, David. I'm a bit surprised there are more than two now. Must be the editing function here. Sorry about that.